# BackboneJS control which attributes get posted

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, rest, backbone.js

I have a Backbone Model which has 3 attributes;

```
attr1
attr2
attr1and2 (concatenation of attr1 and attr2)
```

Now I have a REST call which I call using

```
this.model.save(this.model.attributes, {
                    success: function (model){}
})
```

On the Resource layer, I have;

```
public MyVO createSomething(MyVO myVO) {
}
```

I want to submit only attr1and2 to the server.
Currently all the 3 attributes are submitted and I get an Unrecognized field error for attr1 and attr2.

My question is can I control the attributes that I post to the server (so that I post only attr1and2)

Comment: the ``save()`` first parameter set the attributes, so i guess something like ``this.model.save({attr1: this.model.get("attr1"), attr2: this.model.get("attr2")}, [...]);`` should work.

Comment: Actually I do not want to post attr1 and attr2 to the server at all....Since on my Resource layer in MyVO, I only have attr1and2

Comment: what are the variables you have in your VO? Cause if you do not have these attr1 and attr2 variables on server side VO then they will surely give error for unrecognised fields.

Comment: I do not have attr1 and attr2 in my VO, which is why I do not want to post these....I have attr1and2 and a couple of other otherattr3, otherattr4